# Use Aggregate function in order by of LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I want to use SUM(Quantity) in order by clause here -

```
var top3Order = (from order in ekartEntities.Orders
                         join inventory in ekartEntities.Inventories on order.InventoryId equals inventory.InventoryId
                         group order by new
                         {
                             inventory.InventoryId,
                             inventory.Guid,
                             order.Quantity
                         } into g
                         orderby g.Key.Quantity descending //sum(Quantity)
                         select g.Key.Guid).Take(3).ToList();
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from using .Sum() here. Here's a working example :

```
var top3Order = (from order in ekartEntities.Orders
                 join inventory in ekartEntities.Inventories on order.InventoryId equals inventory.InventoryId
                 group order by new
                 {
                     inventory.InventoryId,
                     inventory.Guid,
                     order.Quantity
                 } into g
                 orderby g.Sum(o => o.Quantity) descending
                 select g.Key.Guid).Take(3).ToList();
```